# kibana unable to discover - (Shard Failures) / Error: indexPattern.fields is undefined

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Kibana is unable to initialize when starting, it shows the misleading exception "Shard Failures" without any details:

[image: kibana]

But when digging in the Browser console, the following logs  have been written:

```
"INFO: 2016-11-25T13:41:59Z
  Adding connection to https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/elasticsearch

"  kibana.bundle.js:63741:6
config initcommons.bundle.js:62929
complete in 459.08ms  commons.bundle.js:62925:12
loading default index patterncommons.bundle.js:62929
Index Patterns: index pattern set to logstash-*  commons.bundle.js:8926:17
complete in 125.70ms  commons.bundle.js:62925:12

Error: indexPattern.fields is undefined
isSortable@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:85441:8
getSort@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:85448:47
__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__</getSort.array@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:85463:15
getStateDefaults@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:85015:16
__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__</<@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:85009:47
invoke@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:31569:15
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</</instantiate<@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:36227:25
nodeLinkFn@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:35339:37
compositeLinkFn@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:34771:14
publicLinkFn@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:34646:31
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:57515:8
invokeLinkFn@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:35880:10
nodeLinkFn@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:35380:12
compositeLinkFn@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:34771:14
publicLinkFn@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:34646:31
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:34790:17
controllersBoundTransclude@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:35407:19
update@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:57465:26
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:43402:16
commitRoute/<@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:57149:16
processQueue@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:41836:29
scheduleProcessQueue/<@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:41852:28
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:43080:17
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:42891:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:43188:14
done@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:37637:37
completeRequest@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:37835:8
requestLoaded@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:37776:10
 <div class="application ng-scope" ng-class="'tab-' + chrome.getActiveTabId('-none-') + ' ' + chrome.getApplicationClasses()" ng-view="" ng-controller="chrome.$$rootControllerConstruct as kibana">  commons.bundle.js:39568:19

Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: "Bad Request"
KbnError@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:62016:21
RequestFailure@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:62049:6
__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__</</</<@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:88628:16
processQueue@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:41836:29
scheduleProcessQueue/<@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:41852:28
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:43080:17
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:42891:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:43188:14
done@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:37637:37
completeRequest@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:37835:8
requestLoaded@https://monitoring.corp.com/elk-kibana/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=9732:37776:10
  commons.bundle.js:39568:19
```

I'm aware of the https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6460 issue, but we don't have any signs of an entity which is too large.

I also recreated the indexpattern already, without luck (deleting and creating).

However when going into the "Settings" > "Index pattern" where the fields are shown, and going back to discover, kibana seems to work again (until next browser refresh). Any ideas how to fix kibana?

- Kibana version: 4.4.2
- Elasticsearch version: 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the `server.maxPayloadBytes` property in the kibana.yml file to an appropiate size solved the issue.

Comment: Hi! Would you be so kind as tu share the _appropiate size_ that you mention... I'v already tried 100MB and the error persists. I think I'm pushing it too much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Our current setting uses `server.maxPayloadBytes: 4194304`